# Не работает foreach в JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

Вот jsp файл:

UPD: Если навести на "${listUser}" Idea почему-то пишет "Cannot resolve variable"

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Management Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>User Management</h1>
    <h2>
        <a href="new">Add New User</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="list">List All Users</a>

    </h2>
</center>
<div align="center">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <caption><h2>List of Users</h2></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUser}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.country}" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit?id=<c:out value='${user.id}' />">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="delete?id=<c:out value='${user.id}' />">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот как он отображается в хроме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не работает foreach? Почему выводит просто jstl тег, вместо конкретного значения юзера? Сам лист точно не пустой, в pom.xml jstl зависимость присутствует

Comment: @Drakonoved а как его заполнить? Не совсем понял, что имеется в виду

Comment: @Drakonoved listUser это название моей переменной (листа), но Idea подсказывает Cannot resolve variable

Comment: @Artem откуда оно берётся? Как попадает в контекст JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо изменение web.xml и перемещение index.jsp не в корень webapp, а глубже, например в webapp/WEB-INF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

</web-app>
```

Стоит отметить, что моё решение справедливо только для проекта, созданного с помощью Maven -> maven-archetype-webapp.